# How to create Submission form for content uploads in Sharepoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to create Submission form standardized with a pull down menu for the various functions - Newsfeed items, content uploads, Weekly Buzz submissions, bug/ feedback etc.Where as newsfeed items ,content uploads ,Weekly Buzz submissions, bug/ feedback are document libraries.Thank you.
[image: FirstImage]

[image: SecondImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to library settings --> Advanced Settings and make sure "Management of Content Type" is selected as yes.

Once you have done this,  update the "Document" content type and add a new choice for category with options to categorize your content,  make sure to make this as a mendatory field.

Once you do that,  all the documents will ask you for filling in values for this field.

Comment: Another option would be to develop an Infopath form that allows file attachments.

Comment: Hi Sudhir,How to update the Document content type and add a new choice for category

Comment: if you enable managmenet of content types,  in the document library settings page you will get an option for updating document content types.

Comment: Hi Sudhir,I added two screenshots of document library settings page after enable the management of content types above.I Couldn't find an option for updating document content types. Could you tell me Which option I have to use from above screen shots

Comment: @user3536897, Never update the OOB content types. Create your own custom content type which inherit from the document content type and add the additional site column required(In your case choice field).Add this content type to your library using "Add from existing site content types" setting(In second screenshot).Once you have added then make that content type as default using "Change the New button order and default content type setting in your second screenshot. Hope this helps.

Comment: @DevendraVelegandla yes that's correct,  dont update the existing content type,  create a new one and inherit the same from "Document" content type,  this will allow you to add new fields.

Comment: Thank you so much Devendra and Sudhir.What is the best way to start designing the form.Is it better to create an application page and add the file upload control.Based on the doc  it has to add to the particular doc library.Or is it better to create a custom content type.

Comment: @sai content types are definately the best way,  you get more control when you create content type,  you also get an option of adding workflows specifically to the content types.  I would suggest you to read more on Site Columns and Content Types.

Comment: Thank you so much Sudhir for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: @Sai glad that it helped you,  mark this as answer...